# Add metadata to memory

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to create a simple function to allocate space on the heap for an object of a given size plus space for some extra meta data that is being used internally.

What i want to do in steps when allocating the size x:

1. Allocate using malloc, allocate x + sizeof(struct metadata) using malloc. Result => start_adr
2. Assign metadata to first byte in start_adr
3. Return pointer to start_adr + sizeof(struct metadata)

I have problems with step 2. How do i assign the value of my argument meta to the first byte in start_adr?

```
struct metadata{
    unsigned char data;
};

void *myMalloc(int size, unsigned char meta){
    int meta_sz = sizeof(struct metadata);      // size of metadata
    void *ptr = (void *)malloc(meta_sz + size); //pointer to our space in memory

    //Magic code for assigning meta here

    return (void *)(ptr + meta_sz); // return memory slot (with meta exluded)
}
```

Comment: Careful with alignment. As-is, what you're doing won't work portably (and might have real bad performance implications when it does work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting some specific error? or do you just not know how to do it?

If I understand correctly it should be as simple as this:

```
struct meta_data * foo = ptr;
foo->data = meta;

return ptr+sizeof(struct meta_data);
```

To read given only the returned ptr:

```
struct meta_data * foo = ptr-sizeof(struct meta_data);
printf("%hhu\n", foo->data);
```

Remember when freeing:

```
void myFree(void * ptr) {
    void * malloced_ptr = ptr-sizeof(struct meta_data);
    free(malloced_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works great! How would i do it the other way around (ie reading the meta)?

Comment: @AntonGildebrand That's harder. You'll need to keep either the initial `ptr` `malloc()` returned, or keep the length of the malloced memory, because, you need to know `ptr` to read `meta` and you need to know it so you can later `free()` the memory.

Comment: Do i need to know this even if the meta is always the first byte of the address?

Comment: @AntonGildebrand I've updated my answer with more information. I incorrectly read your initial question regarding what math you did on the returned pointer, it should be simple to read and later free from what info you have. I also updated the first part of my answer to use your `struct meta_data`.

Answer (score 0):

In an allocated memory space, its adress it's a pointer to the first byte. So, you just need to assign to it the metadata you want and return it. Also, there is no need to convert the malloc return (actually, it is void*, so in this case it is pointless anyway). Note that this works because meta is unsigned char (i.e. 1 byte). In other cases, you need to convert ptr to a struct metadata* (if it has more members, for example). There is also no need to cast it before return

void *myMalloc(int size, unsigned char meta){
    int meta_sz = sizeof(struct metadata);      // size of metadata
    void *ptr = (void *)malloc(meta_sz + size); //pointer to our space in memory

```
*ptr = meta;

return (ptr + meta_sz); // return memory slot (with meta exluded)
```

}

Note that this may be a bad programming practice, as it contradicts the convention that a pointer to an allocated memory space is a pointer to the first byte of it. It would be better if you work with a pointer to the actual metadata, knowing that the first byte in the allocated space is metadata.